# jquery slide animation do not loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

My script does the job correct on the first click but not for the return and especially in the 2nd round.

I want to perform that what happens in the first turn again and again especially reversed. Furthermore I think I made it more complicated than necessary or?
**Does anyone have an idea how to improve this to become a loop?**
[ ***[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/datoart/q0rb5624/2/)*** ]

```
    function goto(id, t){
            //animate to the div id.
            $(".slider_box_vert_mid")
                .animate(
                    {"left": -($(id).position().left)}, {
                duration: 400,
                easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
                queue: false
            });
            $(".slider_box_vert_mid2")
                .animate(
                    {"right": -($(id).position().left)}, {
                duration: 400,
                easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
                queue: false,
                complete: function() {
                    $(".slider_box_vert_mid").toggleClass("hidebox");
                    $(".slider_box_vert_mid2").toggleClass("hidebox");
                    $(".slider_inner_slide")
                        .animate(
                            {"left": -($(id).position().left)}, {
                        duration: 1000,
                        easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
                        queue: false,
                        complete: function() {
                            $(".slider_box_vert_mid3").toggleClass("showbox");
                            $(".slider_box_vert_mid3")
                                .animate(
                                    {left: '0'}, {
                                duration: 400,
                                easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
                                queue: false
                            });
                            $(".slider_box_vert_mid4").toggleClass("showbox");
                            $(".slider_box_vert_mid4")
                                .animate(
                                    {right: '0'}, {
                                duration: 400,
                                easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
                                queue: false
                            });
                        }});
                    }
                });

            // add active class to the current link
            $(t).addClass('active');
        }
```

**CHANGE 1**

Doubeling the function for doing it back is possible for sure but not a real solution of course

Comment: I read something about to toggle with div:not is this possible? Or does anyone no an equal script I can learn from?

Comment: As it stands, you have a strictly "two box" design with box-1 hard-coded with sections 1 and 2, and box-2 hard-coded with sections 3 and 4. I think you would be better off with a generalised widget that is free from hard-coded content and obtains its content dynamically when the animation runs. That way, it will work with any number of sections and you can execute eg `goto(0)` or `goto(7)` and the widget will grab the required content from a "library" of available sections. If you can start thinking along those lines, then the issues you are having will largely disappear.